# Run time error while building apk in ionic

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic2, ionic-native

I initially had cordova 8.0.0. when trying to run **ionic cordova run android** I faced the following issue.

**Ionic build fails with Error: Cannot find module ‘…/cordova/platform_metadata’**

I followed this thread [link here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-build-fails-with-error-cannot-find-module-cordova-platform-metadata/116108/10)

Now am facing different issue as follows

**TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null**

Can somebody help me how to resolve this?

Comment: Your question is very vague. Can you share what your js code is?

Comment: Am not having any code issues.. Just that am unable to build apk for my project... ionic serve is working well but when I run ionic cordova run android the above error shows up